# gradle-wrapper.properties not being picked up by Gradle

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, gradle, androidx

I'm trying to get an Android project to build with the latest version of Android Studio. The project was put together by someone else.

When I try to build the project I get an error saying "Configuration `:app:debugRuntimeClasspath` contains AndroidX dependencies, but the `android.useAndroidX` property is not enabled, which make cause runtime issues. Set `android.useAndroidX=true` in the `gradle.properties` file and retry."

In the gradle-wrapper.properties file I can see the property has been set. There is no gradle.properties in the project "Gradle Scripts" section. Only two build.gradle files, proguard-rules.pro, gradle-wrapper.properties, local.properties and settings.gradle.

How can I go about debugging this project? I'm struggling to find any related issues.
I have tried adding a gradle.properties file but get the same error.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within `gradle-wrapper.properties` this is pretty useless, as that is a properties file for the Gradle wrapper, not the actual build. I would really wonder if any plugin would search the value there, Gradle for sure is not.

`gradle.properties` is exactly the file where you should set that property. The file should be in the project directory, maybe you created it in the wrong place when it did not work, or you did not put the correct content into it.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I added a gradle.properties file to the root of the project and reopened Android Studio - I had a prompt come up to "Migrate to AndroidX" so I followed the wizard through. The migration only changed a testImplementation line but the gradle.properties file then appeared in the Gradle Scripts section and the project builds now :)